# Set TC build comment through

Tags: teamcity

using [TC REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild) it is possible to trigger a build with a comment. Sush comment is shown next to the build. So it is handy to embed more data (metadata) to each build.

TC also support interaction with scripts using [Service Messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ServiceMessages). I was wondering if it is somehow possible to set the build comment using Service Message or any other way during build execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already familiar with TC REST API, then nothing can stop you from [pinning/unpinning](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildPinning) the build with a commment from a build step during the build. You can use bundled ant runner for this.

Comment: Right, so it is not possible through Service messages. REST API will work, but in our case the benefit will not pay off the complexity. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is no service messages, that could possibly help. The complexity of making a simple rest invokation from ant script is not that high, afaik. Maybe it worth trying out on a sample build configuration

Comment: Essentially I don't want to put more logic into our already complicated shell scripts just to add such a small additional value. Thanks.